# how can i convert NSString to String

Tags: swift

Im trying to convert a NSString from a text field to a standard String so that I can check if it contains a certain character.

I have tried

```
var nSStringText = textField.text! as NSString
var stringText = nSStringText as String
```

```
output

'NSString' is not convertible to 'String'
```

Comment: `textField.text!` is already a `String`

Comment: But I wonder where the error message comes from, one can bridge between String and NSString freely. I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just to make sure: This is about an iOS app, and textField is an instance of UITextField?

Comment: yes the text field is from an iOS app

Comment: Im new to swift. Could you please explain what is the difference between nsstring and string?

Comment: Basically, any class/struct name  that starts with NS are from the Objective-C era and all without the prefix are the new Swift only replacements.

Comment: This is _not_ a bad question and I have upvoted since I have it as well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
let myNSString: NSString = "I'm iOSDev"
let myString: String = myNSString as String
print(myString)
print(myString.isEmpty)
```

Casting Refer to `myNSString as String`

Also, You don't need to cast textField text as NSString it's by default String 
So, Just use

`var myString: String = myTextField.text ?? ""`

I Couldn't comment so Posting as Answer

Comment: You  can safely force unwrap the text property: `myTextField.text!`

Comment: Yes, We can no doubt

Answer (score 1):

NSString and String are bridged. You don't need to, and can't, cast from one to the other. As vacawama says in his comment, a `UITextField`'s text property is already of types `String`.

Comment: What do you mean with *“and can't  cast from one to the other”*? The posted code compiles for me (assuming that textField is an instance of UITextField).

Comment: "You don't need to".  If we need to use `String` in the rest of the app then how is it we don't need to?

Answer (score 0):

```
let plainString = "borat"                    // from String
let nsString = NSString(string: plainString) // to NSString
let backToString = String(nsString)          // back to String
```

`String` has a number of initializers, one of which takes an `NSString`. Conversely, `NSString` also has a number of initializers, one of which takes a `String`. Use these initializers to transition between the types.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.